# No data available in table using DataTables with AJAX and JSON file

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to populate a table with a JSON file using DataTables, but every time I load up the page, the table just shows "No data available in table".

This is my current code:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Mail</th>
        <th>Confirmado</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            "ajax" : {"url":"/personas.json", "dataSrc":""},
            "columns" : [
                {personas : "id"},
                {personas : "nombre"},
                {personas : "apellido"},
                {personas : "email"},
                {personas : "confirmado"}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is a piece of the JSON code:

```
{
    "personas": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "Aurelia",
            "apellido": "Osborn",
            "email": "aureliaosborn@lovepad.com",
            "confirmado": false
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Curry",
            "apellido": "Jefferson",
            "email": "curryjefferson@lovepad.com",
            "confirmado": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what I get when I load up the page (part of it):

[image]

And just in case it might be the problem, this is the directory of the JSON:

[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

`"ajax" : {"url":"/personas.json", "dataSrc":""}`

to

`"ajax" : {"url":"/personas.json", "dataSrc":"personas"}`

By specifying `dataSrc` you tell that you use `personas` array from your `personas.json` as your data source.

See these for reference:

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html

Also, as was already mentioned, your array `[` opening bracket doesn't have a matching `]` closing bracket.

Here's a working example with your data:

https://jsfiddle.net/onLuw2pa/165/
I've changed your JSON objects to arrays of values (by doing this you don't have to specify `columns`):

```
{
   "personas":[
      [
         0,
         "Aurelia",
         "Osborn",
         "aureliaosborn@lovepad.com",
         false
      ],
      [
         1,
         "Curry",
         "Jefferson",
         "curryjefferson@lovepad.com",
         true
      ]
   ]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/onLuw2pa/169/
And here's an example which uses your exact JSON.

Comment: Hi dziraf, I've changed the code as you said, but now I get this message: "DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0". The missing bracket is there, I just copied it wrong here. Also, I need the JSON to work as it is now. I can't change it unfortunately.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more precise. Look at jsfiddles, the second one uses your exact json.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your 'personas' data is malformed json. It is missing a closing array brace. It should be:

```
{
"personas": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "nombre": "Aurelia",
        "apellido": "Osborn",
        "email": "aureliaosborn@lovepad.com",
        "confirmado": false
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Curry",
        "apellido": "Jefferson",
        "email": "curryjefferson@lovepad.com",
        "confirmado": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Oh no, sorry, it does have it, I just copied it wrong.